# Change default search engine in the web browser

Tags: android, search, browser, default

Is there a way to change Android default browser search engine to another search engine?

If anyone has tried, please give the details or the way you did it.

I will very grateful to the people who reply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906892/is-there-a-way-to-change-browsers-default-search-engine

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings > advanced > set search engine. For my android 4.0.x, it's the first one under that. They'll give you a list to choose from, but right now I don't know any options to add your own if you don't want to write code. Here's a possible source if you do: http://hoelz.ro/blog/adding-duckduckgo-as-an-android-browser-search-engine

Just replace duckduckgo with whtever else you want, I suppose.